# Android Mat to JPEG converting to inverted Colors

Tags: android, image, opencv, bitmap, jpeg

I have an app. You can take pictures with it. 
If a picture gets captured, `onPictureTaken()` gets called. In this Method it gets converted to a Bitmap and afterwards i save it on the local Storage.

```
@Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        MatOfByte raw=new MatOfByte(data);
        Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(raw,Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
        Mat tmp = new Mat();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2BGR);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bmp);

        storeBitMap(bmp);
    }
```

I dont know why, but when i open the picture on my fileManager it has inverted colors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without the cvtColor method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i accidentally put the wrong params

in Utils.matToBitmap(mat, bmp). Should be: Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp)

now everything works fine.